# `git clone` leads to `fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address`

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to run a GitHub Actions workflow within a private repo that syncs it to a public one.

Part of doing this is cloning this repo (the peculiarities of https://github.com/actions/checkout make it unusable, see bottom):

```yaml
    - name: Checkout
      run: git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test-private.git
```

which fails with

```
Run git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test-private.git
  git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test-private.git
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    TOKEN: ***
Cloning into 'sync-test-private'...
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Full action:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 */1 * * *'

env:
  TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      run: git clone https://$TOKEN@github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test-private.git
    - name: Move
      run: cd sync-test-private
    - name: Sync
      run: git pull --rebase https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test
    - name: Commit
      run: git push --force
```

---

If I use

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v4
```

I get a different more obscure issue.

```
Run git pull --rebase https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test
From https://github.com/JonathanWoollett-Light/sync-test
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging src/main.rs
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in src/main.rs
Rebasing (1/1)
error: could not apply 34b15ec... Sync action
hint: Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
hint: "git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
hint: You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
hint: To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
Could not apply 34b15ec... Sync action
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: The merge conflict looks like you have made some changes on top of the code that was available in `sync-test` repo. If 2 repositories have different histories and when git doesn't know how to autoresolve ( this happens when the same portion of the code is _changed_ in both the repos ) some merge conflicts, you get the error you are getting.

Comment: @HarishGanesan It works locally without a merge conflicts.